# Using bitmap to raise contrast in xamarin.forms causing type load exception

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bitmap, typeloadexception

I have some code where I need to convert a `Stream` into a `Bitmap`, then a class I downloaded called a [LockBitmap](https://efundies.com/cs/LockBitmap.txt). After modifying it, I convert the `byte[]` in `LockBitmap` back into a `Stream`. Here is the method:

```cs
    public Stream RaiseContrast(Bitmap bitmap1)
            {
                LockBitmap bitmap = new LockBitmap(bitmap1);

                bitmap.LockBits();
                var raisedby = 30.0;      
                var contrast = Math.Pow((100.0 + raisedby) / 100.0, 2);

                for(int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
                {
                    for(int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
                    {
                        System.Drawing.Color prev = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                        var red = ((((prev.R / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0;
                        var green = ((((prev.G / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0;
                        var blue = ((((prev.B / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0;
                        if (red > 255)
                            red = 255.0;
                        else if (red < 0)
                            red = 0.0;
                        if (green > 255)
                            green = 255.0;
                        else if (green < 0)
                            green = 0.0;
                        if (blue > 255)
                            blue = 255.0;
                        else if (blue < 0)
                            blue = 0.0;

                        bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(prev.A, (int)red, (int)green, (int)blue));  
                    }
                }
                bitmap.UnlockBits();
                Stream m = new MemoryStream();
                m.Write(bitmap.Pixels, 0, bitmap.Pixels.Length);
                return m;
            }
```

The TypeLoadException only occurs when I add the following code to call the method(it runs perfectly fine otherwise):

```cs
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(photoStream); //photoStream is the original image
Stream photoStream2 = RaiseContrast(bitmap);  //calls the method above
bool success = await api.SetImage(photoStream2);  //where I need to use the new stream
```

The last line of code works with `photoStream` when I comment out the first two lines. The error itself is:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'MedInfoDetect.MainPage+<CameraButton_Clicked>d__3:<bitmap>5__3' (7) due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000021 from typeref (expected class 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' in assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51') assembly:System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51 type:System.Drawing.Bitmap member:(null)
```

`MedInfoDetect` is the solution, `MainPage` is the `.xaml.cs` file, and `CameraButton_Clicked` is a button listener that runs all of the code above. The issue with the error is that the program crashes when `CameraButton` is clicked, before any of the bitmap code, so I can't use the debugger. What is causing the error and how can I fix it?

Things I've done:

- used the debugger(crashes before reaching the code causing the error)
- added nuget plugin System.Drawing.Common
- added statement `using System.Drawing;`

Comment: use the debugger to step through the code until you hit the exception, or use the stack trace to determine which line is causing it

Comment: The problem is that the debugger crashes right when I click the button that opens the camera, before any of this code runs. When the 3 lines above are removed, it doesn't crash. I can't figure out what's causing the issue since I can't reach the code where the issue is caused. What exactly is stack trace, and how can I use it to find the exact line causing the error?

Comment: I assumed you were using Android bitmaps.  You cannot use System.Drawing classes in an Android app - they are tied to the WIndows GDI and not available in Android or iOS.  You either need to do with with Android bitmaps or a cross-platform library like SkiaSharp

Comment: So since I am writing this code for both android and iOS, do I have to avoid System.Drawing bitmaps and Android bitmaps? Also, can you raise the contrast of an image with skiasharp? Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You either have to use a cross-platform library like Skia or write the bitmap code per-platform and expose it via DependencyService

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably just write native code and then use DependencyService. Thanks for your help!